# Intellij - Can not type @ character in the editor

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I have been having this problem for a week, I can not type "@" symbol on my editor. I had research on Google, but I could not find anyone who had this problem before. Did somebody have the same or a similar problem?

I can type "@" character in other parts of Intellij such as Project Structure tool etc.

I checked whether my keyboard configuration is changed. However, all other symbols work properly.

Here are the details of my Intellij version:

**IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4**

**Build #IU-171.4694.23, built on June 6, 2017**

**JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 x86_64**

**JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o**

**Mac OS X 10.12.5**

It would be best to hear some advices.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you assigned `shift + 2` to a shortcut in keymap?

Comment: Did you install any third-party plug-ins like Typing Corrector?

Comment: @CrazyCoder The only plugin I installed was Lombok plugin. However, I issued this problem long after I installed that plugin.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, you were right. I tried to solve this issue by setting the same shortcut for @ symbol. Then the Intellij said that this shortcut is assigned to FindBugs plugin. I uninstalled the plugin and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugins can take certain hotkeys. This can be checked by trying to assign the same key to any action in IntelliJ IDEA Keymap settings, it will warn you about the conflicting action with the same hotkey. So you either remap that action to a different hotkey or disable the plug-in if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Spotbugs plugin was using @ sign as a shortcut. When I tried to assign option+Q(@ sign in my keyboard) It warned me as @CrazyCoder said.

If you are using Mac go to Preferences -> Keymap and you will find out the plugin which is using this shortcut.